Next.js: router.query returns undefined in dynamic route, causing infinite re-renders and bypassing always false conditions
Next.js: router.query returns undefined in dynamic route, causing infinite re-renders
I'm having an issue with my Next.js app where I'm trying to fetch data about a game using a code included in the URL. For example, for the URL localhost:3001/4fac3e, I'm using router.query to extract the gameCode. However, router.query seems to be returning undefined, which is not the expected behavior.
This causes my fetch request to execute with gameCode = undefined, What's more, the if (!router.isReady || !gameCode) return; line seems to not work, leading to infinite re-renders and eventually crashing the app.
this is my directory structure:
pages  ├── [gameCode]  │   └── index.tsx
and this is the index.tsx file
'use client'

import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const GameIndex = () =\> {
const \[game, setGame\] = useState(null);
const router = useRouter();
const { gameCode } = router.query;

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!router.isReady || !gameCode) return;
    
        fetch(`/api/game/${gameCode}/`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => setGame(data))
            .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching game:', error));
    }, [router.isReady, gameCode]);
    
    return (
        <div>
            {game ? (
                <div>Game Data: {JSON.stringify(game)}</div>
            ) : (
                <div>Waiting for game data...</div>
            )}
        </div>
    );

}

export default GameIndex;

I've tried tweaking the conditions, but with no success.

I recommend using Nextjs' getServerSideProps for this. At the bottom of your file you could place the like:
export async function getServerSideProps(context: any) {
    const gameCode = context.params.gameCode;

    return {
        props: {
            gameCode,
        },
    }
}

And then destructure the props like:
const GameIndex = ({ gameCode }) => ....


thanks for the response. i edited the site according to your advice, but the issue still persists. maybe something outside of the provided snippet is malfunctioning?

Can you provide a link to your github repo? Or provide the file where you're using router to navigate to the [slug] page?

hi, thanks for the kind response. this is the link to the file in my github repo.

Hello, turns out the issue was in me fetching data to context before collecting necessary data, so the problem was in a completely different place. thanks for your help, getServerSide props is working as expected :)

Sweet, should my answer be marked as the answer then?
